# Segmentation fault when returning an array

Tags: c++, arrays, return-value

I was trying to solve [this code](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-missing-and-repeating2512/1#). We have to return an array as an output to the function. The function in which I have to code is given like this.

```
 int *findTwoElement(int *arr, int n) {
        // code here
    }
```

When I am declaring my `ans` array, like given below form and returning it, I am getting a `segmentation fault`

```
int ans[2];
ans[0]=b;
ans[1]=a;
        
return ans;
```

But when I am declaring my `ans` array, like given below form and returning it, it is working fine

```
int *ans=new int(2);
   
ans[0]=b;
ans[1]=a;
    
return ans;
```

EDIT--> Then how come this code (given below) is working correctly if the first code is returning `segmentation fault`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int* fun()
{
    int arr[100];
 
    /* Some operations on arr[] */
    arr[0] = 10;
    arr[1] = 20;
 
    return arr;
}
 
int main()
{
    int* ptr = fun();
    cout << ptr[0] << " " << ptr[1];
    return 0;
}
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: You can't return a C-array from a function.

Comment: `int ans[2];` defined `ans` as a *local* variable. Its life-time will end when the function returns, leaving you with an invalid pointer.

Comment: The second code isn't correct, either, as you only allocate space for one `int`. You'd want `new int[2];`.

Comment: Hey, I have made an edit

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude then how come the last code runs fine?

Comment: @sweenish then how come the last code runs fine?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), where sometimes things might *seem* to work (but doesn't really), just to break when you least expect it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude XD

Answer (score 4):

If `int ans[2];` is declared inside functions, it is an array having *automatic storage duration* and its life ends when returning from the function, so you must not use pointers to that after returning.

Also note that `int *ans=new int(2);` is not allocating a 2-element array but allocating single `int` with the initial value `2`. It should be `int *ans=new int[2];` to allocate an array.

Comment: I have made an edit, can u please tell then why that last code runs fine?

Comment: It is by chance. Maybe there were enough space on the stack to prevent the data from being overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

The last code may run fine because not every invalid pointer automatically causes a segmentation fault. It may still point to the region of the memory that belongs to your program, so you may be able to read and write into it. There's just no guarantee that it won't be overwritten at any moment.